# Finding Impedances on a Network

Tags: impedance, alternator

[image: The question]

Hey there the first part of the question (finding the new C value) is pretty easy. However I am stuck at the second part, it asks me to find the empadance values and etc. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Get Grammarly addon for browser to spell correct for you. ... Impedance  https://www.grammarly.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fejJnF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If 10:1 probe sees Vab=0.2 then Vab=2V

If V1=12Vp and Vab=2Vp then C1=71.4nF
If C1=50nF then Vab=4Vp